# How to find Intersecting and unique strings in specific groups in a pd.dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 98 samples/dataframes of which I have reshaped into one dataframe via concatenation.

The dataframe has been subjected to extensive sorting and filtering for identifying locus' for comparison across its group.

Example.

```
data = {"Overall_Sample":["Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample2", "Sample2"], "Sub_Sample":["Sample1_a", "Sample1_a", "Sample1_a", "Sample1_a", "Sample1_b", "Sample1_b", "Sample1_b", "Sample1_b", "Sample2_a", "Sample2_a", "Sample2_a", "Sample2_b", "Sample2_b", "Sample2_b", "Sample2_b"], "Panel":["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"], "Identified_Locus":["Locus1", "Locus2", "Locus3", "Locus4", "Locus2", "Locus3", "Locus4", "Locus5", "Locus3", "Locus5", "Locus6", "Locus1", "Locus3", "Locus5", "Locus6"]}

df.DataFrame(data)
```

I wish to find intersecting Locus per sampleName between panel a and b.

Desired outcome.

```
Sample1 
Intersecting: Locus2, Locus3, Locus4
Panel a unique: Locus1
Panel b unique: Locus5

Sample2
Intersecting: Locus3, Locus5, Locus6
Panel a unique: None
Panel b unique: Locus1

with 3 different lists, 
intersection = (3,3)
Panel a unique = (1, 0)
Panel b unique = (1, 1)
```

The goal is to make a percentage barplot in the end.

I have succeded manually to split the dataframe and retrieve the desired output. But I would like to avoid to split the dataframe - is it possible to keep it at the main dataframe and still retrieve the desired output?

The code I used to manually identify intersecting and unique ones.

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.Sub_Sample)
sample1_a = grouped.get_group("Sample1_a")
sample1_b = grouped.get_group("Sample1_b")

sample1a_locus = sample1_a["Locus"].tolist()
sample1b_locus = sample1_b["Locus"].tolist()

sample1a_set = set(sample1a_locus)
sample1b_set = set(sample1a_locus)

Overlap_locus = sample1a_set.intersection(sample1b_set)
Panel_a_unique = sample1a_set.symmetric_difference(sample1b_set)
Panel_b_unique = sample1b_set.symmetric_difference(sample1a_set)

Overlapping_genes.append(len(Overlap_locus))
Panela_unique.append(len(Panel_a_unique))
Panelb_unique.append(len(Panel_b_unique))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is not bad. Here's a slightly more concise approach that scales also to larger data sets.

You can get the unique values for `Identified_Locus` per sub sample with

```
locus_per_sub_sample = df.groupby(['Overall_Sample', 'Panel'])['Identified_Locus'].apply(lambda grp: set(grp))
```

You can then perform set operations on the different samples rather easily. E.g., to get the number of shared elements between the sub-samples for `Sample1` you can do:

```
len(set.intersection(*locus_per_sub_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice['Sample1', :]]))
```

Similarly, for the unique elements of the sub-samples `Sample1_a` and `Sample1_b`:

```
symmetric_difference1 = set.symmetric_difference(*locus_per_sub_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice['Sample1', :]])
```

To get the symmetric difference for each sub sample

```
locus_per_sub_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice['Sample1', :]].apply(
     lambda r: r.intersection(symmetric_difference1))
```

which gives you

```
Overall_Sample  Panel
Sample1         a        {Locus1}
                b        {Locus5}
Name: Identified_Locus, dtype: object
```

Comment: It worked nicely!

One concern for retrieving the unique elements in the sub-samples.

set.symmetric_difference(*locus_per_sub_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice['Sample1', :]])

out[1]: {"Locus1", "Locus5"}

Although, this is correct - Is it possible to have it seperated? 

desired:
out[2]: {"Locus1"} 
out[3]: {"Locus5"}

Comment: @LVES0067 Feel free to ask for further improvements or to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I went with creating a for loop to append a list, respectively. The list will be needed for creating a percentage bar chart for easy visualization in a presentation.

```
names = df.Overall_Sample.unique()
Overlapping_locus = []
Sample1_unique = [] 
Sample2_unique = []
for i in names:
    Overlapping_Locus.append(len(set.intersection(*locus_per_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice[i]])))
    Sample1_unique.append(len(locus_per_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[i], :]].apply(lambda u: u.intersection(set.symmetric_difference(*locus_per_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[i], :]])))[0]))
    Sample2_unique.append(len(locus_per_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[i], :]].apply(lambda u: u.intersection(set.symmetric_difference(*locus_per_sample.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[i], :]])))[1]))
```